# Unable to Map Table

Tags: vb.net

Hi I am keep getting this error unable to find Table Mapping[Table] or Data Table. I am using Visual Basic 2013 for desktop and I have a Microsoft Access Table table called crap and the name of my access file is Student.accdb. My data set is called StudentDataSet1. I added the database through Database Explorer and the state is Open. I'm not a programmer I'm just playing with Microsoft Access and VB. Also I entered the connection string and it still doesn't work. Can someone help with this?

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Fill retrieves rows from the data source by using the SELECT statement
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\Student.accdb")
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim sql As String
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    sql = "Select * from crap "
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "AddressBook")
End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim Department As String

    Dim i, ID As Integer
    Dim rw As DataRow
    'Add a new row to the Student table.
    rw = StudentDataSet1.Tables(0).NewRow
    ID = InputBox("Enter your ID")
    Department = InputBox("Enter your Department")


    rw.Item("ID") = ID
    rw.Item("Department") = Department

    Try
        StudentDataSet1.Tables(0).Rows.Add(rw)
        'Update the Student table in the testdb database.
        i = da.Update(StudentDataSet1)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    'Displays number of rows updated. 
    MessageBox.Show("no of rows updated=" & i)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you fill a DataSet you have the option to give a name to the datatable loaded. You have given the name "AddressBook". This name should be given again when you call the Update method later in your code

```
 i = da.Update(StudentDataSet1, "AddressBook")
```

When you call the Update method another problem should be considered. Usually the OleDbDataAdapter cannot update/delete/insert new record if it has no commands to execute these operations. You could write your own commands and set the properties InsertCommand, UpdateCommand and DeleteCommand of the DataAdapter, but for single table query like yours above you could use an handy class that creates these commands for your PROVIDED THAT YOUR SELECT COMMAND RETURNS THE PRIMARY KEY OF THE TABLE

```
' Move it at the global scope here to reuse the same adapter when you call the update
Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim sql = "Select * from crap "
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    Using con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(.....)
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        Dim builder = new OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
        da.InsertCommand = builder.GetInsertCommand()
        da.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand()
        da.DeleteCommand = builder.GetDeleteCommand()
        da.Fill(ds, "AddressBook")
    End Using
End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' Use the global adapter created at the form load 
    ' Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    ' da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    ......    
    Try

        i = da.Update(StudentDataSet1, "AddressBook")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    MessageBox.Show("no of rows updated=" & i)
End Sub
```

Comment: Steve, I called it student instead and of Address book and my Dim ds as StudentDataSet but I keep getting Update requires a valid InsertCommand when passed DataRow collection with new rows.

Comment: That's another problem, I will try to update the answer.

Comment: Steve I just tried this out and I can't build my solution because OleDbCommandbuilder is not defined. I have Visual Studio 2013 for desktop. I can show you what I have now.

Comment: The OleDbCommandBuilder is a class defined in the System.Data.OleDb namespace. This namespace is not imported by default in a VB.NET project (Just System.Data) and this is the reason that force you to prefix every class like OleDbConnection with OleDb.OleDbConnection. So you have two options. Add OleDb. in front of OleDbCommandBuilder or (recommended) add the import of System.Data.OleDb in your project and remove the prefix OleDb from your actual declarations

Comment: Anser updated with the OleDb prefix in front of the OleDbCommandBuilder declaration

Comment: Steve I was just about to say that when I typed this in visual basic asked me I wanted to add OleDbCommandbuilder as a class

Comment: Also how do I send you my updated code because now I'm getting the method or operation is not implemented. da.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand(), I made this a method because of VB asked me if I wanted to changed it to this

Comment: I think that this question/answer has diverged too much from the initial problem. I suggest you to post a new question with the actual code to get more attention from other users of the site. If you find that my answer has helped you could upvote or accept it.